# An expression to say " the things belong to a situation make sense, seem reasonable and are consistent with each other"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example; we have an incident which has a murder thing, and police interrogates someone, and that person's claims seem reasonable with the situation, make sense and consistent with the characteristics of the situation so what kind of expression could be used for defining this type of situation?

Comment: hang together, sit well, are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

“ The particulars of this situation are **in order**.

**in order**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+order) an idiom

> - Suitable, correct, & appropriate